# How to implement MVVM in Windows Phone 8.1 app (xaml)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

Could anyone give an example of implementation? Is it done with ViewModel implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` (and raising events, as it's done in Silverlight) or some other way? How is ViewModel bound to the view?

All examples I've found so far are incomplete or outdated (refer to Silverlight apps, **not** Xaml ones).

Comment: I have a [simple MVVM example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) on my blog if you're interested. As Abdurrahman said, MVVM is a pattern so the pattern would be the same regardless of if you're using WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: It's worth investigating some MVVM frameworks, Caliburn Micro now supports WP8.1 and Universal apps.

Comment: @Rachel AFAIK MVVM is supproted out of the box in Silverlight. That means **no** external dependency of any kind, you can wire it up yourself quite easily. The API is different in XAML apps.

Comment: @Arnthor I'm not sure what you're meaning by "out of the box". MVVM is a pattern to follow while designing your application, and can easily be used with both WPF and Silverlight with no 3rd party tools. The link I added in my first comment is a simple example that does not use any 3rd party components. It sounds like you found what you were looking for though, so good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I currently use the following approach in my own Universal/W8.1/WP8.1 apps. This approach uses the [RArcher WinRT Toolkit](http://rarcher.azurewebsites.net/Toolkit), which is an experimental toolkit based on the MVVM pattern. 
It provides a way to maintain app state and you can use the `ViewModelBase` to implement INPC. 
It also uses the [Unity dependency injection container](https://unity.codeplex.com/).

I'd start with making the `ViewModelLocator` an application-wide resource, so my Views can access it easily.

```
<Application.Resources>
     <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
</Application.Resources>
```

The view can use it like so:

```
<Page.DataContext>
     <Binding Source="{StaticResource ViewModelLocator}" Path="MainViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

The `ViewModelLocator` looks like this:

```
public sealed class ViewModelLocator
{
     public ViewModelLocator()
     {
         RegisterIoCBindings();
     }

     public IMainViewModel MainViewModel
     {
         get { return IocContainer.Get<IMainViewModel>(); }
     }

     private void RegisterIoCBindings()
     {
         IocContainer.Container.RegisterType(typeof(IMainViewModel), typeof(MainViewModel), 
         null, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
     }
}
```

The `MainViewModel` has the `ViewModelBase` as baseclass and implements the `IMainViewModel`:

```
public sealed class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMainViewModel
{
     private string myText;
     [AutoState] 
     public string MyText
     {
         get { return myText; }
         set 
         { 
             myText = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
     }

     public MainViewModel() // You can use constructor injection here
     {             
     }
}
```

That is the basic setup. And as the others have stated, MVVM is a pattern and there a many ways to use it. I would say, use what feels good ;-)

If you like to know more about this approach, check out the toolkit and unity DI.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, I'll go check some frameworks, like the one you described. I'm **really** disappointed though, if there's no way to get MVVM out of the box.

Comment: You can wire it up yourself of course, if that is what you mean with "out of the box". Just implement INPC on your viewmodel, and you're almost finished.

Comment: I would be careful about using that ServiceLocator pattern. Like stated the framework contains unity so you might as well inject the viewmodels into the views and not have the views take these sort of dependency hits.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of Windows RT I would advise to look towards [PRISM](https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/). It provides really good modern development practices. You will get suitable navigation service, app lifecycle management, great MVVM support and very flexible view and ViewModels resolution mechanism.
You can easily add it to your project via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.StoreApps/).
It has pretty good documentation, so if you have any questions you can find an answer on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130643.aspx) or even download free book [Prism for the Windows Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39042). Our team has successful experience in building projects using PRISM.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, it's the same. Because MVVM is a pattern. You can implement it to your windows phone app easily. I'm using MVVM Light for my wp apps and EventToCommand behavior to raise events. I have an app open sourced on [GitHub](https://github.com/akoken/Jirabox), you can check it out if you want.